# Java Swing GUI combobox issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, jcombobox

I’m having a strange issue with my swing GUI. I’m trying to make a refresh button clear a combo-box list to refresh the components. Its not working and I’ve probably just made some stupid mistake. Here’s my code:

```
public class GUI2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private JPanel contentPane;
public JComboBox combobox;
public ReadJoystick stick;
private JButton refresh;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI2 frame = new GUI2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GUI2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    StickWidget Left = new StickWidget();
    Left.setName("Left Stick");
    contentPane.add(Left.draw(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    StickWidget Right = new StickWidget();
    Right.setName("Right Stick");
    contentPane.add(Right.draw(), BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ReadJoystick stick = new ReadJoystick();
    JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox<Object>(stick.read().toArray());
    combobox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXX"); 
    panel_1.add(combobox);
    JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    btnRefresh.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(btnRefresh);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    combobox.removeAll();
   }
}
```

This code currently reads the joysticks available to the computer and displays them in the combo-box list. Below is a picture of my current GUI:

[image: Screenshot of my GUI]

Every time I press the refresh button it throws this error:

```
typeException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.GUI2.actionPerformed(GUI2.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: [Please try to search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249336/removing-all-items-from-a-combo-box-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeAll` is a method which is inherited from `Container`, which is intended to remove all the child component contained by a container...not really what you want to do.

Instead, you could use `combobox.setModel(null)` or `combobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel())` which will change the data/model which was backing the combobox previous to a empty version

Swing backs many of it's components with a separate "model", which makes it easy to switch out what is displayed by the views

The `NullPointerException` is coming from the fact that you've shadowed your `combobox` variable in your constructor

```
public GUI2() {
    //...
    JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox<Object>(stick.read().toArray());
```

This is leaving the class instance field as `null`, instead it should just read

```
combobox = new JComboBox<Object>(stick.read().toArray());
```

Have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details